# Why my solr multi shards have duplicate docs

Tags: solr, hbase

I use solr and **hbase lily** to store data that are from hbase. My solr version is **5.3.0**.

I create a solr cluster with two shard.When i put data to hbase,i find the solr collection has some duplicate docs on different shards .I create collection shards's mothed is:

> On one solr node I use solr core admin page to add a core name with
>   `HealthProfile1` for collection `HealthProfile`. And then on another node
>   I add a core name with `HealthProfile2` for the same collection.

[image]

My question is: Is my create shards method correct?

Comment: Why are you creating the cores individually? Why not just create a collection on the cluster?

Comment: I create solr with lily,but lily is not compile with solr correctly.Now i modify lily source code with my solr version,system is correct.